# claim from? or claim to? which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

Which one is right?
For example, I sold A company's products and need to claim commission.

I claim commission from A company.

I claim commission to A company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim is sometimes used with different prepositions. For example, it is very common to say that one has a claim *to* something. However, in your example, that's not what you're saying — instead, you have a claim *to the commission* ("I claim commission. . ."). That commission, however, comes *from* the company, and so one could say any of:

> *I claim commission from [company].*
>
> *I lay claim to commission from [company].*
>
> *I have a claim to commission from [company].*

If that claim is not in dispute, it would be more common to say claim *on*:

> *I have a claim on commission from [company].*